# JQuery Dropdown with image inside (not working on IE)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using jquery dropdown with image from this link :

http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown

Which is very nice and cool jquery plugin.

And the problem is it is working fine on Firefox, Google Chrome and Safari.

However, it is giving me problems in IE especially IE6.

It is giving me error message "No such interface supported" in IE6.

I have looking through on google and still couldn't find how to solve it.

Has anyone got any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The demo there is working fine in my IE6, you'll need to show your implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the workarounds here: http://cdivilly.wordpress.com/2007/11/26/no-such-interface-supported/